# Bootstrap model validation

Tags: self-study, references, bootstrap, validation

For predicting the true error of a model there seems to be a bootstrap method which as far as I know is used as follows:

1. From the dataset $\mathcal{D}$ you extract $m$ subsamples $B_1, ..., B_m$  of the same size of $\mathcal{D}$ with reemplacement,
2. You train the model with each $B_i$ and predict $\mathcal{D}$, computing a measure of the error.
3. You compute the mean of the error vector.

Now this  obviously produces an optimistic measure of the error, as you are predicting a lot of elements that were in the training sample. There is obviously something I am missing here, What has to be done in order to estimate the error of the model? Is bootstrap valid for estimating the error? Because to me it seems this is only valid for estimating the variance.

--UPDATE--

I have run some tests and I am obtaining aproximately $3\%$ less classification error compared to 10-Fold, so this indeed seems to be underestimating the error. You can never be sure because K-Fold overestimates the error. So I would automatically discard this method as an estimator for the error and only use it to estimate the variance of the error.

Comment: The bootstrap can be used for more than estimating variance.  In particular you can also estimate bias.

Comment: Suppose we are building a linear regression model using the bootstrapping, now we have m subsamples of the same size. for each of the m model which you built you will get a value of error( assuming that is RMSE). So we will have RMSE for each of the m model and then we are taking the average of those m  error values which is the estimated error of the model and the variability of the error value across the m models would the variance of the RMSE.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I don´t see how you can estimate bias, indeed the method seems to already have an optimistic bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Introduction To The Bootstrap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412042312), Section 17.6, recommends a different method than the one you describe. This is the ".632" bootstrap.

For each bootstrap sample, approximately .632 of the elements will be used (some more than once). Train the model for this iteration on these elements, and calculate the train error (on the same elements), and the test error (on the elements not chosen).

The train error obviously underestimates (as you note in the question). The test error, however, overestimates: it checks the performance of a model built on instances of which some were duplicated. A derivation shows that the approximation (for this iteration) should be a weighted average: 0.368 of the train error, and 0.632 of the test error.

As usual in the bootstrap, confidence intervals are built based on the distribution of several of these approximations (each of which is the weighted average above).

The book contains more details.

Comment: Thank you, that´s a good reference and the bootstrap $.632$ is particurlarly interesting. So to my question, the simple bootstrap I have explained cannot be used to estimate error, only variance. In order to estimate error you have to use $.632$ bootstrap.

Comment: These bootstrap estimates of classification error rates do adjust for bias in the naive estimator.  You can check Efron's book as referenced in the answer by Ami Tavory or my (2007) book which also includes the .632+ estimator..

Comment: @MichaelChernick It's really cool you wrote that book.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So what is wrong in my question? I can only see a rather large optimistic bias because of the weight in-sample error meditions